# PySpark - Spark clusters EC2 - unable to save to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have set up a spark cluster with a master and 2 slaves (I'm using Spark Standalone). The cluster is working well with some of the examples but not my application. My application workflow is that, it will read the csv -> extract each line in the csv along with the header -> convert to JSON -> save to S3. Here is my code:

```
def upload_func(row):
    f = row.toJSON()
    f.saveAsTextFile("s3n://spark_data/"+ row.name +".json")
    print(f)
    print(row.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL data source example") \
        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.csv("sample.csv", header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")
    df.rdd.map(upload_func)
```

I have also export the `AWS_Key_ID` and `AWS_Secret_Key` into the ec2 environment. However with the above code, my application does not work. Below are the issues:

1. The JSON files are not saved in S3, I have tried run the application few times and also reload the S3 page but no data. The application completed without any error in the log. Also, the `print(f)` and `print(row.name)` are not printed out in the log. What do I need to fix to get the JSON save on S3 and is there anyway for me to print on the log for debug purpose?
2. Currently I need to put the csv file in the worker node so the application can read the csv file. How can I put the file in another place, let say the master node and when the application runs, it will split the csv file to all the worker nodes so they can do the upload parallel as a distributed system?

Help is really appreciated. Thanks for your help in advance.

**UPDATED**

After putting Logger to debug, I have identified the issue that the map function `upload_func()` is not being called or the application could not get inside this function (Logger printed messages before and after function call). Please help if you know the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to force the map to be evaluated; spark will only execute work on demand.

`df.rdd.map(upload_func).count()` should do it